# Caching for css content for iphone FB APP

Tags: iphone, css

I'm trying to create a webpage for the iphone FB app wall link .  When I try to use margin attribute on a div for the webpage,  the margin attribute doesn't take affect when clicking on the wall link.  If I view the same page in safari iphone browser the margin does take affect.  It seems like it has to do with extra caching by Facebook of the CSS file.  When I change the background color in the css file, the changes get propogated everywhere but inside the FB web browser on the iphone app.

Comment: Do you have a link to a page using what you are describing it is hard for us to answer without actual code to look at

Comment: actually it only happens when clicking the link on my wall. if i go to the web browser on the iphone it is ok.  it seems like fb browser does some extra caching of the css?  has anyone encounted this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found that FB wall post does some extra caching.  to remove the caching, just pointed the css file to another file first, then switched it back after reloading the link from the wall post.