# Facebook Application Link and JS SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

Hello guys I have two small questions about my facebook application link and JS SDK. So let me explain:

1- Well as I understood from Facebook JS SDK, the [image] should be left just empty. But still I am a little dizzy and I want to make sure  whether we should put our page content into it or it should be left empty?
Please make me sure about it.

2- I have put some changes in my *css* and *markup* of my page but after one day I can not see some of the changes in my facebook application link.
How can I see the result of changes if there is such a way??

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer this for you:

1) Yes, It should be left empty and here's the info on why it's required quoted from [JS SDK docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/):

> The JavaScript SDK requires the `fb-root` element in order to load properly and a call to 
>   `FB.init` to initialize the SDK with your app ID correctly.
>
> The `fb-root` element must not be hidden using `display: none` or
>   `visibility: hidden`, or some parts of the SDK will not work properly in
>   Internet Explorer.
>
> The SDK inserts elements into `fb-root` which expect to be positioned
>   relative to the body or relative to an element close to the top of the
>   page. It is best if the `fb-root` element is not inside of an element
>   with `position: absolute` or `position: relative`. If you must place the
>   `fb-root` element inside of a positioned element, then you should also
>   give it a position close to the top of the body or some parts of the
>   SDK may not work properly.

2) It's most probably a cache problem, there's a similar question with an issue of css which has been answered previously: [Caching for css content for iphone FB APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101364/caching-for-css-content-for-iphone-fb-app)

Also to get your browser/visitors browser to re-fetch your CSS file, The trick is to pass a query param/variable at the end of the CSS file url like so: `?v=1`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1">
```

This will automatically make your browser or maybe even facebook to fetch your CSS file again with the new changes. Make sure to change the number everytime you update your files so you could see the changes instantly.

Comment: No problem Arash! You might wanna select this answer by clicking the tick/check mark below the voting buttons :)

Comment: What you mean? If you mean the CSS changes, then try the above method i mentioned and it should fix the issue, if not can you be more specific with what you really mean?

Comment: Here is my page [link](http://doitflash.com/demo/myappera/) but it is different in my facebook app [link](http://www.facebook.com/myflashlab/app_422254927834307)    Please check these two links so that you can get what I mean exactly dear SIR.

Comment: Ok i found the problem, your page tab url shows content from this url: `http://doitflash.com/demo/myappera/index.php` but your site loads index.html as the default index file which is why you see different content. `http://doitflash.com/demo/myappera/index.html` this has different content and the `index.php` has different content, change your tab url or remove the `index.html` file, whatever you want to keep.

Comment: Yes, The reason why you don't see the changes is because your tab app loads different url and you're making those changes on `index.html` file which is loaded when you visit your site, so update your page tab url with the correct url and it'll work as you want, hope this works for you.

Comment: Let me check that for you, give me few mins!

Comment: Okay, Add this function `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();` inside your `fbAsyncInit` function and below `FB.init`. This function will auto grow your tab height and remove scrollbar automatically. Also if you want to get more details, you can check their docs for this function [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/)

Comment: SIR? see my facebook link again plz. The srcollbar removes but it is flashing and then it removes. Why?

Comment: Yes, That's because the function fires after the page loads fully! This is why it happens, you can set a fixed height in your app to avoid this, but it wouldn't make much difference. Try it though!

Comment: Yes man, it is fixed to 800 but it does not make much difference as you said